# adb severe error in xubuntu

Tags: adb, xubuntu

OK I saw this has been asked a few times but it seems it was all for windows. I am trying to learn some android development with my xubuntu machine. But I am not a linux expert either... 
After following along with a tutorial to set up Eclipse and Android SDK-linux I tried to get my first hello world to run and I got this:

```
    [2012-11-04 09:42:22 - xdasdka] ------------------------------
[2012-11-04 09:42:22 - xdasdka] Android Launch!
[2012-11-04 09:42:22 - xdasdka] The connection to adb is down, and a severe error has occured.
[2012-11-04 09:42:22 - xdasdka] You must restart adb and Eclipse.
[2012-11-04 09:42:22 - xdasdka] Please ensure that adb is correctly located at '/home/orange/code/android-sdk-linux/platform-tools/adb' and can be executed.
```

I have adb in the path listed. I have also cd to the directory and adb kill-server but it returns adb command not found. Just to make sure I also chmod +x adb and it still does not work.

I almost forgot to add I am on a 64bit machine.

Any ideas?